# Saving photo with added overlay to photo library

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimageview

I'm making an app where the user takes a photo, an overlay is placed over the image, and the user can then save the image or upload it to Facebook or other sites.

I have managed to get the app to take the photo, and to make the overlay I am using a `UIImageView`, which is placed over the top of the photo.

I'm not sure how exactly I can export the image, with the overlay, as one file, to the photo library, or to Facebook.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this?

Comment: Yes, see the answer below. Just draw the images in the imageview you create, and you can make a UIImage from the contents using this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the idea. This code may need a tweak or two, though. (I admit that I haven't run it.)

Your `UIImageView`'s base layer can render itself into a CoreGraphics bitmap context (this will include all the sublayers, of course), which can then provide you with a new `UIImage`.

```
UIImage *finalImage;
// Get the layer
CALayer *layer = [myImageView layer];
// Create a bitmap context and make it the current context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.bounds.size);
// Get a reference to the context
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// Ask the layer to draw itself
[layer drawInContext:ctx];
// Then ask the context itself for the image
finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
// Finally, pop the context off the stack
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

These functions are all described in the [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).

There's also a slightly more complicated way that gives you more control over things like color, which involves creating a `CGBitmapContext` and getting a `CGImageRef`, from which you can again produce a `UIImage`. That is described in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide, section ["Creating a Bitmap Graphics Context"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE).

Comment: Note that if you want to draw a view with its hierarchy you should use the renderInContext: method of the CALayer class.